# How to treat missing values for time since occurence

Tags: regression, predictive-models

I have a data set with the start and end date of different financial products, such as accounts, loans, debet and credit cards, etc.

I am tying to predict purchase of a given product.

This data allows me to make variable such as time since purchace of any of the other products, as well as time since a product was ended. But for a lot of products, most customers will have missing values on these day-since-variables, since they haven't bought the other product. For a decision tree, this poses no challenge. But how should this be treated in a regression type model? They certainly don't have a 0 days since purchase. One could argue a very high value could make sense - for most products, purchasing another product shortly before is an important predictor. Is there a common practice here? would a mean or median imputation make sense?